# Trying to pass an array object to my web service controller but it always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax

I just want to pass an array object from my javascript to controller. though up to alert it gives checkbox value,So i believe there is nothing wrong in javascript.  In controller the object is null always. what did i do wrong here?

```
function amal() {

var selected = [];

$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {

    selected.push($(this).val());
});
alert(selected);

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:63138/api/Emptbles/LoadAmal",
    type: "POST",
    data: selected,

    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert("success");
        myFunction();
    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
```

My api controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult LoadAmal(List<selectedSymptoms>list)
    {
        string item1 = "";
        string item2 = "";
        string item3 = "";


        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i += 3)
        {
            //grab 3 items at a time and do db insert, 
            // continue until all items are gone..
             item1 = list.ElementAt(i+0).ToString(); ;
            item2 = list.ElementAt(i + 1).ToString(); ;
            item3 = list.ElementAt(i + 2).ToString(); ;
            // use the items
        }

        string query = "EXEC Add_Employee'" + item1 + "','" + item2 + "','" + item3 + "'";

        int result = connectionProvider.CreateSomething(query);


        return Ok(result);
}
```

My selectedSymptoms class(i dont know whether this is right,just want to take jason object to the controller. thank you)

```
public class selectedSymptoms
{
    public void PassThings(List<selectedSymptoms> symtoms)
    {
        var t = symtoms;
    }


}
```

Comment: Need to see what `selectedSymptoms` looks like. The objects need to share the same properties so the serializer can map properties from the Request. This would be different if it was type `List<string>` (or another simple type)

Comment: Posting code in comments doesn't work. You'll need to edit your question

Comment: @Mark i added the rqquested class. could you please have a look at it?

Comment: Did my answer help? If not I will delete it

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you're running into is a serialization issue between the object you're sending and the Web API. Microsoft [gives you code to test this process](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#testing_object_serialization), which I would recommend you use because it will teach you a lot.

What you're sending in your response would probably look like this :

```
["someValue1", "someValue2", "etc"]
```

The `Type` in your API needs to be serializable, and there's no possible way of doing that given your current class. If all you want to do is send a list of strings, then you should not use a complex object at all and simply use `List<string>`. If you do indeed want to use a complex object, it needs properties to map the data to.

If I had a class

```
public class Person 
{    
     public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

And I wanted to post a javascript object representation of that, my code would look like :

```
var people = [];

$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
    var Person = new Object();
    Person.Name = $(this).val();
    people.push(Person);
});

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:63138/api/Emptbles/LoadAmal",
    type: "POST",
    data: people,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (response) {
    },
    error: function () {
    }
});
```

You can see how we are basically creating an array of a JavaScript-version of our C# class, and it can easily map the `Name` property between the 2 objects.

API would look like :

```
public IHttpActionResult GetStuff(List<Person> peeps) {}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
data: { 'list' : selected }
```